# Reading the Stars

Tags: visual

As the human explorers ventured into an uncharted system, they got the feeling that their presence was expected. In fact, the stars themselves greeted them.

[image: Stars]

**What was the greeting?**

Comment: Is zooming in required?

Comment: @McMagister Nope.

Comment: Brilliant Question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mesage is

> Peace

Explanation

> Juxtapose the image and a 180 degrees rotated version of the image, then remove all the stars that appear in both images, and the word "Peace" is formed twice.
> [image: Peace]

My original answer would be

> "Z", because if you highlighted all the stars that are not square, you get a "Z".
> [image: Zshape]

Comment: Congratulations. You were 5min faster than me. Well done!

Comment: Edit your answer with the correct one and I will remove my answer leaving the "Z" interpretation.

Comment: Nei, it's fine as it is. It's not a race - but an **excellent** puzzle.

Answer (score 8):

I think what the starts try to tell humans simply is

> **Turn around!**

the reason being:

> There is a 2-fold rotational symmetry in the image, I.e. You can turn it around by 180 degrees and it is the same...

It should be added that

> Other interpretations like "your future is like your past" or "look behind you before going onward" etc. are also possible, but I took the first one which jumped to head...

---

**Edit:**
On closer inspection (now with a computer at hand)

> The image is not 100% rotational symmetric. Only some stars are. The following image highlights this in colour
>  [image]
>  Red --> Original stars
>  Green --> 180degree rotation stars 
>  Yellow --> 180degree rotation overlapping positions

Therefore I might need to look a bit deeper...

> Ignoring the 'yellow' parts leaves only dots which - rotated by 90 degrees' spell out PEACE.
>  [image]